# no logro conectar la terminal con myswl, me salta comando no reconocido cada vez que escribo mysql

Tags: mysql, xampp, mysql-workbench, terminal

Ya he descargado mysql installer, mysql workbench, xampp y activado mysql, pero cuando quiero crear bases de datos desde la terminal y escribo : , mysql -u root -p me salta que "mysql no se reconoce como un comando"

Comment: Bienvenido a SO ES Puedes hacerte un [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de camino ganar tu primera medalla. Desde donde lo abres, terminal de windows o MySQL, luego lo abres con permisos de administrador. :-)

Comment: ¿Si escribes en la Terminal `which mysql` qué muestra?

Comment: ¿En cuál sistema operativo?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Por alguna razón mysql (que es mariadb) no está en tu path.

Si xampp se instaló bajo /opt/…, necesitas encontrar la carpeta/bin/ por dentro que contenga mysql. De ahí puedes agregar esa carpeta a tu path desde la terminal y debes poder conectar. Sí no puedes modificar tu path, puedes usar el path entero cada vez.